# Python difference between input and raw_input?

Tags: python

is the 'input ()' function used to input an integer? And the raw_input () function is used to input a string?

Comment: When you type in a question, it shows you similar questions in the box. Try reading them first.

Comment: Although [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x) is tagged with python 3, the answers also reference python 2 and might be helpful.

Comment: Not quite. `raw_input()` is used to input a string, `input()` is used to input danger. :) `input()` in Python 2 invokes the `eval()` function, and that can be dangerous - see [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO member Ned Batchelder. That article covers some advanced Python concepts, but it may help you understand that using `eval()` on random user input is not wise.

Answer (score 2):

`input` evaluates the input, while `raw_input` does not.

For example, capturing the `input` `5`, returns the `int` `5`. However, capturing the `raw_input` `5`, returns the `str` `'5'`